# Ubuntu 13.04 near-fresh install: 'ps aux' gets stuck on anacron

Tags: command-line, kernel, anacron

I've just finished an install of Ubuntu 13.04 onto a brand new PC, and noticed that executing 'ps aux' in a terminal causes it to hang half-way through displaying a list of the processes:

```
$ ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  27076  2872 ?        Ss   15:20   0:00 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:20   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    15:20   0:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
[...trimmed...]
root      1207  0.0  0.0  20972   996 tty6     Ss+  15:20   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
root      1219  0.0  0.0  70428  2812 ?        Ss   15:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
```

...and it stops there, without returning to the command prompt.  Pressing Ctrl-C to try to abort the listing doesn't terminate ps, and just displays ^C in the terminal.

Curious, I ran strace on it, and found ps was blocking on a read() call while trying to fetch the command line for the anacron process:

```
[...trimmed...]
write(1, "root      1207  0.0  0.0  20972 "..., 91root      1207  0.0  0.0  20972   996 tty6     Ss+  15:20   0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
) = 91
stat("/proc/1219", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
open("/proc/1219/stat", O_RDONLY)       = 6
read(6, "1219 (cups-browsed) S 1 1219 121"..., 1023) = 193
close(6)                                = 0
open("/proc/1219/status", O_RDONLY)     = 6
read(6, "Name:\tcups-browsed\nState:\tS (sle"..., 1023) = 777
close(6)                                = 0
open("/proc/1219/cmdline", O_RDONLY)    = 6
read(6, "/usr/sbin/cups-browsed\0", 131072) = 23
read(6, "", 131049)                     = 0
close(6)                                = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=331, ...}) = 0
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=331, ...}) = 0
write(1, "root      1219  0.0  0.0  70428 "..., 88root      1219  0.0  0.0  70428  2812 ?        Ss   15:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
) = 88
stat("/proc/1239", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
open("/proc/1239/stat", O_RDONLY)       = 6
read(6, "1239 (anacron) D 1 1239 1239 0 -"..., 1023) = 189
close(6)                                = 0
open("/proc/1239/status", O_RDONLY)     = 6
read(6, "Name:\tanacron\nState:\tD (disk sle"..., 1023) = 772
close(6)                                = 0
open("/proc/1239/cmdline", O_RDONLY)    = 6
read(6,
```

Incidentally, trying to do this also results in a hang:

```
$ cat /proc/1239/cmdline
```

I've found a few other posts by others which have seen this particular phenomenon, but it seems no one has found a solution yet.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10980/suggestions-needed-to-debug-why-ps-ef-gets-stuck
https://serverfault.com/questions/257764/suggestions-needed-to-debug-why-ps-ef-gets-stuck

This is a nearly fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04.  I just downloaded the .iso from the Ubuntu downloads page last night, installed it via USB, and have installed all of the latest updates.  After the install, I added a couple of other applications (nvidia-current, VirtualBox, Audacity, Audacious, Google Chrome, and VLC), but didn't notice this issue with ps until just now.

Hardware specs: Intel i7-3930K @ 3.20GHz, 16GB RAM, Nvidia GeForce GTX 680 (304.88 drivers).

Has anyone else experienced this issue before?  Is there a workaround or kernel patch available?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using kerberos?  I had the same problem when made this change in /etc/krb5.conf...

```
[libdefaults]
 default_realm = MYREALM
 dns_lookup_realm = true
```

...to...

```
[libdefaults]
 default_realm = MYREALM
 dns_lookup_realm = false
```

I was having problems with firefox hanging, and I thought that might be the solution.  Rebooting didn't fix the "ps hanging" problem, but reverting that change and rebooting did.

Comment: This was right after a fresh install, so AFAIK Kerberos wasn't setup, and /etc/krb5.conf doesn't even exist.  There was a kernel update pushed out last Tuesday (5/14) that seems to have fixed this issue for me, for now.  I'll try to post more information if it happens again.